# How do I put EditText into an array?

Tags: java, android, arrays

I want to use numbers separated by commas or spaces and return statistics like mean median mode std dev, etc. How would I go about making an array and using the contents of the array after the use inputs them and do a simple statistical calculation? I'm new to android developing right now, so I'm not too familiar with all the different methods. And no this is not for any schoolwork or homework, I'm making an app and here is proof: https://goo.gl/9mt4ql

```
package erm.customcalculator.fragments;

        import android.os.Bundle;
        import android.view.LayoutInflater;
        import android.view.View;
        import android.view.ViewGroup;
        import android.widget.EditText;
        //import java.lang.*;
        import erm.customcalculator.R;


public class StatsFragment extends CalcBase {

    EditText etnums;
    double nums;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = GatherViews(inflater, container);


        return v;
    }

    private View GatherViews(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_standard_error, container,
                false);
        etnums = (EditText)v.findViewById(R.id.value_p);
        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public String getNameOfCalculation() {
        return getString(R.string.standard_error);
    }

    @Override
    public void clearPage() {
        etnums.setText("");

    }


    @Override
    public String returnMessageIfBadFormData() {
        if(isEmpty(etnums)){
            return "All values required for computation";
        } else {
            nums = getDouble(etnums);

            return "";
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String calculate() throws Exception {

        double total = 0;
        double var = 0;
        for (double element : nums){
            total = total + element;
            double average = total / element;
        }

        double sum = total;

        for (double element : nums) {
            double average = total / element;
            var += (Math.pow((element - average), 2) / element);

        }

        double std_dev = Math.pow(var, 0.5);
        double average = total / element;

        return String.valueOf("Sum: " + sum +
                "Mean: " + average +
                "Standard Deviation: " + std_dev +
                "Variance: " + var);
    }
}
```

Comment: loop through your array and save all in a variable you can use comma or space while saving in variable and then use it to set text in edit text.

Comment: When you posted your code, notice that the lines that are indented 4 spaces end up in a code block, but the closing brace and some of your other statements aren't in the code block because they were not indented. When you paste in code, if it isn't all indented, select the whole block and then click the button that has { } on it -- that will add 4 spaces to the whole block so your code appears correctly. Welcome to StackOverflow!

Comment: PS: There's a pending edit to this question... I assume it is one of the other reviewers fixing your indentation!

Comment: Yes I know Mustanser but I don't know how tot code it like that yet ,

Comment: And thank you srm I did not know that!

Answer (score 1):

An `EditText` contains a `CharSequence` which you can convert into a `String`. You then need to parse the `String` into whatever representation you wish. For example, if the numbers are comma separated, you can use `String.split()` to get the tokens between the commas. Then use `Integer.valueOf()` or `Double.valueOf()` to get a numerical value which you can use for computations.

Comment: So I can enter a list separated by commas and I won't have to declare edit text as editText[] ?

Comment: @LoganLees It's up to you. If you want the user to enter a comma-delimited list, you will need to parse the `String` to get the values. If you use an array of `EditText`s, you only need to convert each value into a number.

Comment: I updated the code to what I have after your comments but I still need help  with the actual coding portion of it because I am still really unfamiliar with what I'm actually doing.

Comment: @LoganLees I suggest you do some research about string parsing. You should start by describing in words the steps you need to follow to accomplish your goal. At first these steps can be quite general. Then refine them into more specific steps as you go. You should also google the functions that I suggest you use and read the documentation that describes how they work.